# How to match text between brackets across multiple lines in python

Tags: python

Say I have a file that I need to process:

```
names = [
    joe
    billy
    kate
]
```

I want to use regex to match the string

```
[
    joe
    billy
    kate
]
```

and remove the newline character within.

I have tried

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
file = "".join(data)
search = re.search(r'= \[[^]*\]', file, re.MULTILINE)
```

but I get the error `sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression`. I have already tried the regex on http://regexr.com/ and it worked fine. What's wrong with my python script?

EDIT:
My real problem looks like

```
names = [
    joe[ggg]
    billy[ddd]
    kate[aaa]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead which asserts that the `]` is only followed by a space or end of the line and it must be preceded by a space character.

```
search = re.search(r'(?s)= (\[.*?\s\])(?=\s|$)', file)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pKLeIE/1)

Comment: What if I have [] inside those elements? like joe[dd]\n so on.. This is my actual problem.

Comment: [I think your link is broken](https://regex101.com/api/regex/delete/csE2gHrnT3juSDEM8BCETIlo)

Comment: Note that `(?=\s|$)` = `(?!\S)`, shorter and smarter :)